# .htaccess - избежать повторного выполнения для определенного правила

Tags: .htaccess, apache

```
RewriteRule /?\.bar$ - [F,L]
```

Проблема в том, что сервер добавляет / после foo.bar и начинается циклическая переадресация.

Что можно сделать для срабатывания этого правила лишь один раз, при этом чтобы другие правила продолжали работать как обычно.

Comment: F|forbidden
Using the [F] flag causes the server to return a 403 Forbidden status code to the client. While the same behavior can be accomplished using the Deny directive, this allows more flexibility in assigning a Forbidden status.
When using [F], an [L] is implied - that is, the response is returned immediately, and no further rules are evaluated.

Comment: Я натыкался на это, однако в моем случае .htaccess продолжает выполнять свои темные дела

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правило составлено с ошибкой, у него нет второго параметра, который указывает на новый (переписанный) адрес. Правильная запись этого правила выглядит следующим образом:

```
RewriteRule /?\.bar$ - [F,L]
```

**Update**

Как выяснилось в комментариях, сервер сам приписывает `/` после адреса, если адрес не указывает на файл. В этом случае можно использовать следующий вариант директивы:

```
RewriteRule /?\.bar\/*$ - [F,L]
```

Она срабатывает как при наличии символа `/` в конце адреса, так и при отсутствии.

Comment: Пробовал и так. В результате идет циклическая переадресация и меня скидывает на foo.bar//

Comment: @rinart73 Только что проверил на `xampp`. Выдаёт 403, как и заказано.

Comment: В конфигах сервера прописано добавлять / к всему, что не файл. Как это побороть?

Comment: @rinart73 Как именно это прописано? И в каком файле?

Comment: Не в .htaccess. Как прописано, я не знаю, доступа нет -_-

Comment: @user64675 Обновил ответ.

Comment: Все равно циклическая переадресация

Comment: @user64675 Тогда либо ошибка в других строках `.htaccess`, либо работе мешают невидимые Вам настройки `Apache`. Попробуйте как-нибудь выяснить содержимое `httpd.conf` и файла вашего `vhost`. Если у Вас внешний хостинг, можно попытаться задать вопрос техподдержке.